# Unpack tuple in LINQ lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, tuples

I have a LINQ query that uses tuples for optimization.  However, I'm unable to find working syntax to unpack the tuple in the arguments, which seems surprising because C# does support unpacking tuples and other languages supporting lambdas and tuples do support unpacking.

Is there any way to leverage unpacking in the expression below instead of referencing properties of the full tuple?

```cs
            shelves
                .Select(kv => (kv.Key, kv.Value.Orders.Count))
                .Where(tuple => tuple.Count > 0)
                .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Count)
                .Select(tuple => tuple.Key);
```

Comment: please post sample input and expected output

Comment: If you expecting to do this `.Select(i => (i.Key, i.Count)).Select((key, count) => ....)` - No, not implicit deconstruction into lambda parameters.

Comment: Is there a technical reason why this feature doesn't exist or could we expect to see this future?

Answer (score 12):

C# supports [tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct#deconstructing-a-tuple), but it isn't possible with lambda parameters in your case.

You declared an [unnamed tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples) in `Select` and can access items using `Item1`, `Item2`, etc. properties

```cs
shelves
    .Select(kv => (kv.Key, kv.Value.Orders.Count))
    .Where(tuple => tuple.Item2 > 0)
    .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item2)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.Item1);
```

You may also switch to named tuple syntax

```cs
shelves
    .Select(kv => (Key: kv.Key, Count: kv.Value.Orders.Count))
    .Where(tuple => tuple.Count > 0)
    .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Count)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.Key);
```

Or even use an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), which do not confuse you with properties names (because it uses the same name as the property being used to initialize them)

```cs
shelves
    .Select(kv => new { kv.Key, kv.Value.Orders.Count})
    .Where(x => x.Count > 0)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
    .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: @twinlakes Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Comment: It's an answer - a fine answer - but it's not the answer we want. The answer we want is destructuring the tuple in the lambda arguments. Unfortunately, it's not the world we live in today.